# Mediawiki:Cookies in general

Tags: cookies, mediawiki

I have a general and simple/stupid sounding question about the MediaWiki (MW): Does MW use cookies?

There is not one article nor manual page at all about this topic. Of course the website of MW has a [Cookie Statement page](https://foundation.wikimedia.org/wiki/Cookie_statement) (and Wikipedia links to the same) and this tells they use diff. types of cookies and even tracking pixels (another topic you can't find anything about).

If I log in on my fresh installed Wiki and looking for cookies in the meantime, the browser doesn't show me any cookie from my site. But if I log in on Wikipedia et al. cookies were set.

I did a lot of search about this question and if it is possible to control the application of cookies, but couldn't find any (detailed) article. Due to GDPR I would like to understand how it works in MW and not just copy/paste a cookie statement for my wiki visitors.

This is what I've found until now (but didn't helped at all):
[Manual:SessionManager and AuthManager](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:SessionManager_and_AuthManager)
[Manual:Configuration Settings](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Configuration_settings#Cookies)
[Requests for comment/Survey Cookies/Local Storage on Wikimedia](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Requests_for_comment/Survey_Cookies/Local_Storage_on_Wikimedia)
[Extension:CookieWarning](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Extension:CookieWarning)
[GDPR (General Data Protection Regulation) and MediaWiki software](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/GDPR_(General_Data_Protection_Regulation)_and_MediaWiki_software)

So if possible, please tell me more than "MW is using cookies."

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: It is rather unclear what your question is.

Comment: I'm looking for an overview about the topic "How Mediawiki using cookies" like:  
  
* Mediawiki needs cookies for this and that and using them in this and that way  
* You can/can't disable them. The alternative is ...  
* If you disable them, this and that wont work  
* To take control over the behaviour you can change the manner in this and that way  
  
Something like this. Thanks @Tgr

Comment: But you already link to that page from your question.

Comment: I hope you don't mean the _Cookie Statement Page_ , because this is from mediawiki.org and has at least nothing to do with the software published by MediaWiki. It's just for using there webpage.

Answer (score 0):

Wikis uses cookies. At least the session cookies. But Session cookies are technical needed and you don't need.

[image: Firefox Cookies]

Extensions can bring more cookies in. Especially analytic tools set tracking cookies.